# Disabling the Navigation Tree in phpMyAdmin entirely

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I only use phpMyAdmin for one database browsing, and was wondering if there was a way to turn off the 'Database Tree Navigation' feature completely.

I've tried to comment out the navigation tree at

`/libraries/navigation/Navigation.class.php` 
and

`/libraries/navigation/NavigationTree.class.php`

But this just leaves the page unrenderable.

Comment: Also, there isn't anything in the config to do this.

Comment: What version of phpMyAdmin, php, and what OS are you using?

Comment: OS: Debian Wheezy | Version 4.0.10.8 | php 5.2

Answer (score 1):

For the upcoming version 4.4, it will be possible to disable the databases part of the navigation tree. See this pull request:
https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/pull/1469

This produces a databases drop-down selector in the navigation tree, like in the pre-4.0 versions.